# Fixing PS3 MP4 playback on Firmware 4.11

Tags: ps3

I have just updated my PS3 to firmware 4.11 and it no longer plays MP4/M4V files. (via DLNA using PS3 MediaServer).

The update to the firmware is the only change in the environment.

Is this a known issue, and will files need to be re-encoded differently to work? (AVI files do play fine.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I updated from PS3 MediaServer 1.50 to 1.50.1 and it worked straight away.

Comment: I don't get it. Is the update for the MediaServer the solution for your problem? Then please mark your post as an accepted answer.